# FPDF header() image Can not open image issue

Tags: php, image, fpdf

For FPDF header() image retun below error

> > Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Can not open image file:xxxxx.com

I have checked image path folder & file permission also.

Please any one help how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the image URL to DOCUMENT_ROOT URL

```
$ImagePath ='http:xxxxxxxxxxx.com/image/image1.png';
```

TO

```
$ImagePath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/image/image1.png';


$pdf->Image($ImagePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a subclass of FPDF, called PDF, but you are not using it. Change $pdf = new FPDF() to $pdf = new PDF()

Answer (score 0):

require 'LIBRARIES/FPDF/extended_fpdf.php';
$pdf = new PDF ();

$pdf->Image('ImagePath');

get extended fpdf